# Xperia Z2 Tablet - Is it capable of making phone calls?

Tags: calls, sony-xperia-z

In some promo or hands-on videos I see there's a Phone app on announced Xperia Z2 Tablet but nothing about it from the official sources.

So is it capable of making ordinary phone calls (GSM cellular phone calls, not Skype or something)?

Comment: Have you not thought of checking [this](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_z2_tablet_goes_official-news-7913.php) comes in both Wifi and LTE editions...

Comment: @t0mm13b ask yourself a question. iPad Air LTE version, can it call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this: http://www.modaco.com/topic/370148-mwc-2014-sony-xperia-tablet-z2-hands-on/

and on this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJut4ZawQqw#t=172 (at 2:51)

So LTE versions are capable of making and recieving phone calls.